# Replace Class Name in elements but not remove other class in this elements pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to replace font class in the whole document.
How to do this problem using pure JavaScript without jQuery? Please Suggest! 
I don't want to remove other class in the changing class elements in javascript.How to do?
Here is my project.
**Html**

```
        <span class="switch-unicode">
            <a onclick="changeFont(2)" href="javascript:">
                <i class="icon icon-check"></i>
                <span>Unicode</span>
            </a>
        </span>
        <span class="switch-zawgyi">
            <a onclick="changeFont(1)" href="javascript:">
                <i class="icon icon-check-empty"></i>
                <span>Zawgyi</span>
            </a>
        </span>

        <div class="clearfix">
           <span class="unicode ieUnicode pull-right">Unicode</span>
           <span class="unicode ieUnicode pull-left">Unicode</span>
        </div>
```

**Css**

```
        .unicode{
            border: 2px solid blue;
        }
        .zawgyi {
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
        .pull-right {
            float: right;
        }
        .pull-left {
            float: left;
        }
        .clearfix {
            clear: both;
        }
```

**Javascript**

```
function changeFont(num) {
   var fromFont = 'unicode ieUnicode';
   var toFont = 'zawgyi';
   if ( num==2 ) {
      fromFont = 'zawgyi';
      toFont = 'unicode ieUnicode';
    };
   /* Change classes */
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName( fromFont );
        var i = elems.length;
        while(i--) {
           var item = elems[i]; 
           item.className = toFont;
         };
         return false;
};
```

Comment: And what's wrong with what you have?

Comment: i don't want to remove other class name in changing class elements.How to do.?

Comment: just update classes. i.e document.getElementById("yourElement").className = "MyClass1 MyClass2 MyClass3";

Comment: As example, When <a> click, remove both 'pull-right' and 'pull-left' class.I want to change class 'unicode' and 'zawgyi' only.I don't want to remove 'pull-right' and 'pull-left' class.

Answer (score 1):

`item.className = toFont;`

You're re-assigning the entire class.

Concatenate!

```
item.className += toFont;
               ^
```

Or use the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList) object.

```
item.classList.add(toFont);
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly you just want to change one class with another,you can do it like this:

```
x = document.getElementsByClassName('unicode').item();
 x.attributes.class //say logs out "unicode class1 class2";
 x.attributes.class = "class3 class1 class2"; //replaced unicode by class3
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a poor method, since you have to manually keep track of all classes as you remove and add them.

Comment: this solution was just give an idea of the approach that can be used to solve the issue, no an end solution @SterlingArcher

Comment: I don't mean this in any offense, but why suggest a non-end solution? It's best to offer the best methodology, not just a "it works" solution :)

Comment: sometimes even a hint does the trick, at-least for me.Moreover I understand a fully explained solution should always be preferred.Anyways @SterlingArcher thanks for the comment I will keep it in mind for my future answers

Answer (score -1):

I have added 'hasClass' to check if the a particular element belongs to a class or not. I have also added 'addClass' and 'removeClass' methods to add and remove a class from the specified elements class list. Following is the implementation:

```js
var link1 = document.getElementById("changeFont1");
var link2 = document.getElementById("changeFont2");

link1.onclick = function() {
    changeFont(2);
};

link2.onclick = function() {
    changeFont(1);
};

function changeFont(num) {
   var fromFont = 'unicode ieUnicode';
   var toFont = 'zawgyi';
   if ( num==2 ) {
      fromFont = 'zawgyi';
      toFont = 'unicode ieUnicode';
    };
   /* Change classes */
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName( fromFont );
        var i = elems.length;
        while(i--) {
           var item = elems[i]; 
            if (hasClass(item, fromFont)) {
                removeClass(item, fromFont);
                addClass(item, toFont);
            }
         };
         return false;
};

function hasClass(ele,cls) {
  return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
}

function addClass(ele,cls) {
  if (!hasClass(ele,cls)) ele.className += " "+cls;
}

function removeClass(ele,cls) {
  if (hasClass(ele,cls)) {
    var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)');
    ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
  }
}
```

```css
.unicode{
            border: 2px solid blue;
        }
        .zawgyi {
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
        .pull-right {
            float: right;
        }
        .pull-left {
            float: left;
        }
        .clearfix {
            clear: both;
        }
```

```html
<span class="switch-unicode">
            <a id="changeFont1" href="javascript:">
                <i class="icon icon-check"></i>
                <span>Unicode</span>
            </a>
        </span>
        <span class="switch-zawgyi">
            <a id="changeFont2" href="javascript:">
                <i class="icon icon-check-empty"></i>
                <span>Zawgyi</span>
            </a>
        </span>

        <div class="clearfix">
           <span class="unicode ieUnicode pull-right">Unicode</span>
           <span class="unicode ieUnicode pull-left">Unicode</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code dump answers. A good answer is explained.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Please understand the question properly before declaring someone else'e answer wrong. According to the question on click of the link, the fromClass should be replaced by toClass. Your answer only adds the toClass but is not removing the fromClass.

Comment: I understood the question perfectly. By reading the docs on the `classList` object, one can easily utilize the `remove` method. Not to mention I did not say you were wrong, I asked you to explain your answer. Don't flip out from a comment that has no malice to it.

Comment: No offense meant. I think I did put it the wrong way. I agree with what you said in your previus comment. Documentation has all the information required. I have added a brief explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: @ankur, I want to know this answer. But , i want to save this class in cookies. How to do?